# Connection refused on Docker Mysql with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm having trouble connecting to the mysql database from my php/laravel container. I'm getting a connection refused all the time. The connection works just fine with Mysql Workbench though.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project_db
      MYSQL_USER: dev
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dev
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dev
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    networks:
      - laravel
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php_node
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

And the relevant part of my .env looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=dev
```

I have tried removing everything and building the image again, but to no avail.

Can you guys spot my error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't used it but [reading this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) you need to define the network `networks:  laravel:   driver: bridge` at the end of the composer file. (they use `app-network` though rather than `laravel`)

Comment: I tried that, but it still throws the Connection refused error

Comment: Does mysql allow connections from any IP address or is it limited.  Your request will come from the other containers IP, whereas Workbench is coming from the host.

Comment: Hmm I could check that in the container, I assumed it did because I am using the image

Comment: Try 172.17.0.1 as your DB_HOST in the .env file.

Comment: Can you try with username as dev?

Comment: @Clint This worked the first time that I started the container. The next time it doesn't output anything for a long time, so it is not successful.. I think the ip of the container changes every time I start it.

Comment: @AbhinavManchanda I have tried this first, but started using root for being sure it is no user level problem.

Comment: @Jonas That is very strange it is usually the same IP for the host. Can you take a look here and confirm the container host is indeed changing

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-65-get-your-docker-hosts-ip-address-from-in-a-container

Comment: @Clint The ip address is 172.19.0.3 for the third time I started the container, and 172.20.0.3 the fourth time I start it. It goes on like that for every time I stop and start it again.

Comment: @Jonas Which version of Docker are you using? If it is Docker for windows you should be able to use host.docker.internal

Comment: @Clint This worked indeed, I am using 19.03.2 and macos. I had an error after that saying that the "Mysql server has gone away" but that was just because the mysql server wasn't booted up completely when I was executing some migrations. So thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Docker for windows you can use host.docker.internal to access the host IP.

I answered this in the comments but I thought I'd duplicate it as a proper answer to help anyone who finds this in the future and save them reading all the comments

Answer (score 3):

For extracting docker container names and their IPs use below command in your terminal :

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

It will show you something like :

```
/nginx - 172.18.0.4
/php - 172.18.0.3
/mysql - 172.18.0.2
```

Then use mysql container ip in your .env file

```
DB_HOST=172.18.0.2
```